Python generate_blob_sas generating non-working SAS
I'm trying to generate a blob SAS in python, but I keep getting the following error:
Signature did not match. String to sign used was r...

My function looks like this:
    start_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    expiry_time = start_time + timedelta(days=1)

    sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=account_name,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=filename,
        account_key=account_key,
        permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
        expiry=expiry_time,
        start=start_time
    )

And my resulting URL looks like this:
https://{{storage account name}}.blob.core.windows.net/{{container name}}/{{blob name}}?st=2024-04-25T15%3A04%3A23Z&se=2024-05-02T15%3A04%3A23Z&sp=r&sv=2023-11-03&sr=b&sig={{signature}}


The above error occurs when the signature in the SAS token does not match the expected signature.
Here is the code to generate a blob SAS using the Azure Python SDK.
Code:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions

# Set the storage account details
storage_account_name = "venkat123"
storage_account_key = "accountkey"
storage_container_name = "test"
blob_name = "<Your-blob-name>"

# Set the SAS token parameters
sas_expiry = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(hours=1)
sas_permissions = BlobSasPermissions(read=True, write=True)

# Generate SAS token for the blob
blob_sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
    account_name=storage_account_name,
    container_name=storage_container_name,
    blob_name=blob_name,
    account_key=storage_account_key,
    permission=sas_permissions,
    expiry=sas_expiry
)

# Construct the full URL with the SAS token
blob_url_with_sas = f"https://{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{storage_container_name}/{blob_name}?{blob_sas_token}"

print("Blob URL with SAS token:")
print(blob_url_with_sas)

Output:
Blob URL with SAS token:
https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/example.png?se=2024-04-26T04%3A12%3A16Z&sp=rw&sv=2023-11-03&sr=b&sig=bfRpgp%2BXtGcsJZ3xxxxx


Browser:

Reference:
azure.storage.blob package | Microsoft Learn
